# Add LED to existing water pump

Tags: led

I have zero experience with electrical engineering and am hoping that someone can a) tell me if this is possible, and b) direct me to some material where I can learn enough about this to ask intelligent questions. I can't find anything on a hobbyist level and am not looking for college level courses.

I have a small water pump [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07SJGKFT7/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SJGKFT7)

It is a 3W submursible pump that plugs into the wall. I want to add an LED so that when it is plugged in and running, an LED lights up as well. The LED needs to be waterproof. I plan to use this to make an illuminated tabletop fountain.

Is this a thing that is possible, and if so where can I begin to learn about this? All I can find are college level engineering courses, and I don't even know if this is a thing that can be done.

Sorry if I sound really stupid, this is outside my area of expertise and Google has been no help.

Comment: Adding a light to a watertight pump will be difficult. Why not just have a separate light. https://www.amazon.com/LemonBest-Underwater-Spotlight-Fountain-Landscape/dp/B07Y1QQVGM

Comment: I know I could add a separate light and a separate plug. My question is, is it possible to do what I described, and where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Instead of "engineering" in your search terms, try "DIY".  As in "DIY underwater LED".  See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: #user1483042, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah let me see. Adding a water proof status LED with your mains 110/220VAC waterproof pump is hobbyist easy, and there are a couple of ways to do it. I am assuming you don't want to do fancy things using complicated hardware like Arduino. Please let me know otherwise.

Comment: There are expensive water proof lamps, but if you are a poor hobbyist like me, and have minimum DIY skills, you can buy a cheap, low voltage (DC 5V) low power (0.2W), USB LED lamp, and make it "waterproof", using perhaps heat shrink tube or similar goodies. First. the lamp: AliExpress USB LED Lamp Night Lamp:
https://th.aliexpress.com/item/4001254515616.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.115e3bfbR2iHIV&algo_pvid=b5d95de4-b1fe-49a9-b81e-febb7e3a9e8c&algo_expid=b5d95de4-b1fe-49a9-b81e-febb7e3a9e8c-18&btsid=0b0a556e16104228545422642e962e&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: Any good hobby store ought to offer suggestions with water proof string LEDs and a power supply.   Cheap.  LED’s can leak in water slowly and fail

Comment: you can't get any power from the pump because it's all sealed (potted) up. You can use a switch to toggle power to the pump, and provide the light power from that same post-switch point.

Comment: Clear $1 nail polish, epoxy, and clear spray paint are good methods to waterproof things DIY.

Comment: @user1483042 Can you properly open up the unit and then re-seal it with confidence? It appears that the entire mains supply is brought all the way under water with that unit. (Which I don't like to see, but there it is, anyway.) If you feel able to open it up and modify it, re-sealing it without risk, then I'd open it up and see what is in there and work out a light method once I've collected all the data I need from the examination. Otherwise, a more physical approach is indicated -- no underwater lighting -- but a visible indicator you can highlight using external, directed light perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

***Question***

*How to DIY a waterproof LED lamp?*

---

***Answer***

There are expensive water proof lamps, but if you are a poor hobbyist like me, and have minimum DIY skills, you can buy a cheap, low voltage (DC 5V) low power (0.2W), USB LED lamp ([Ref 1 below](https://th.aliexpress.com/item/4001254515616.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.115e3bfbR2iHIV&algo_pvid=b5d95de4-b1fe-49a9-b81e-febb7e3a9e8c&algo_expid=b5d95de4-b1fe-49a9-b81e-febb7e3a9e8c-18&btsid=0b0a556e16104228545422642e962e&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)), and make it "waterproof", using perhaps heat shrink tube or similar goodies.

Or if you are poor and lazy like me, you can just do the following:

[image: usb led lamp 1]

---

[image: usb led lamp 2]

---

[image: usb led lamp 3]

---

*No Guarantees*

*1. No guarantee it won't work for too many years.*

*2. No guarantee it won't melt down, blow up, or electrocute your fish.*

---

***References***

(1) [AliExpress USB LED Lamp Night Lamp](https://th.aliexpress.com/item/4001254515616.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.115e3bfbR2iHIV&algo_pvid=b5d95de4-b1fe-49a9-b81e-febb7e3a9e8c&algo_expid=b5d95de4-b1fe-49a9-b81e-febb7e3a9e8c-18&btsid=0b0a556e16104228545422642e962e&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

---